# Interesting consequences of $a^n \approx b^m$ (and other numerical coincidences)?

Tags: soft-question, approximation

The values of $2^{19}$ and $3^{12}$ differ from each other by less than $1.5\%$.  This numerical coincidence has an interesting practical consequence:  if we begin with any positive real number $a$ corresponding to the frequency of a musical note, and then multiply by $3/2$ ("go up a perfect fifth") twelve times, we end up on (almost) the same note but seven octaves higher.  The entire 12-tone (chromatic) musical scale rests on this numerical coincidence.  (Another, perhaps less interesting consequence, of this is that we can approximate $\log_2 3 \approx 19/12$, which is accurate to about one part in a thousand.)

Are there other examples of interesting practical consequences of numerical coincidences like this?  (Another, simpler coincidence is $5^3 \approx 2^7$, but I'm not sure if that leads to any interesting applications.). By using the phrase "like this" I am being intentionally vague, which is why I am using the `soft-question` tag; certainly I would be interested in other approximations of the form $a^n \approx b^m$, but I am certainly open to other examples.

Comment: $19^3$ differs by only $1$ from $7^3\times20,$ so $19/7$ differs from $\sqrt[3]{20}$ by less than $1/7500.$ But I know no practical consequences. $\qquad$

Comment: By the way, we also have $2^{11}\approx 3^7$, which gives us the "white keys" only on a piano. --  And $5^3\approx 2^7$ should say something about three major thirds almost being an octave?